# Cannot convert XML with XSLT - in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, xslt-1.0

So I have the XSLT code (it's correct, it's tested separately) and I have it hard-coded as a string (that's a requirement, don't bother asking). Loading the XML, the XSLT and all this stuff is OK.

But when I use the XmlDocument as 1st argument in `XmlCompiledTransform.Transform()` I get exception about `White space handling`.

Then I use the XmlReader as 1st argument, and this works, but I get exception as I try to save the transformed file, and the exception is `Invalid XML document. The document does not have a root element.`

Here is the code:

```
    Dim xsltTransformerCode As New xsltTransformCode()
    Dim myXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim resultXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim sr As New StringReader(xsltTransformerCode.transformationXSLTcode())
    Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr)
    Dim xsltTransCompiled As New XslCompiledTransform()

    'write the stringified xslt code to file, in order to check its validity manually'
    File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\gk\Desktop\tempXSLTcode.xsl", xsltTransformerCode.transformationXSLTcode())
    'load the xml string taken from the database'
    myXmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\gk\Desktop\XTilbud.xml")
    'load the stylesheet'
    xsltTransCompiled.Load(xr)

    Using xw As XmlWriter = resultXmlDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
        xsltTransCompiled.Transform(myXmlDoc, Nothing, xw)
        xw.Close()
    End Using

    resultXmlDoc.Save("C:\Users\gk\Desktop\myXMLfile.xml")

    sr.Dispose()
    sr.Close()
    xr.Close()
```

P.S. I want to transform the original document and pass its value to another xmlDocument and save it. (Or if I can transform and save the same object, then it's ok. I am open for suggestions).

So what I need is somehow to get the value of the reader and save it as XML document or smth like that, I am not sure...

Comment: If you want the transformation result as `C:\Users\gk\Desktop\myXMLfile.xml`, why are you first trying to create an `XmlDocument`, why don't you simply use an overload of the `Transform` method that takes a `FileStream` or `XmlWriter` (e.g. `Using xw As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Users\gk\Desktop\myXMLfile.xml", xsltTransCompiled.OutputSettings)  xsltTransCompiled.Transform(myXmlDoc, Nothing, xw) End Using`)?

Comment: Well, my initial purpose is to save the result from the applied XSLT transformation into an XML document (object) that I can pass over to smth, further. 
The thing I am doing now with `.Save()` is just because of testing purposes, to check if the transformation was successful. 

Btw, I tried your way, and now my newly created XML is empty...

Comment: We need to see the stylesheet code and an input XML sample.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the XML and XSLT, but in the thing that there is nothing being written in the `resultXmlDoc` and that is why I am getting `Invalid XML document. The document does not have a root element`, because it is actually empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little bit over-complicated for this situation.

Try [THIS ONE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163431.aspx).